# Conda package revision issue with setuptools

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, setuptools

I upgraded some Anaconda packages and this completely messed up my code. Now I would like to roll back to the previous installed version and found that

```
conda install --revision [revision number]
```

is getting me back to the my previous packages version. (you can take a look at all package revisions with `conda list --revisions` )

But when I do this I get the following error message related to setuptools:

```
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: failed

RemoveError: 'setuptools' is a dependency of conda and cannot be removed from
conda's operating environment.
```

Does anybody know what the problem is with setuptools?

Comment: There isn't enough information for us to really narrow down the problem for you (it's not clear whether or not you truly need to install a different version of `setuptools`), but I'd generally recommend making a new environment and not attempting to fix a borked environment

Comment: Good idea, thanks!